# Where are all the original household items?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131863/1253) reminded me of a nagging problem in Disney’s “Beauty and the Beast”: at some point in the past, all the castle staff and livestock were turned into china, furniture, clocks, feather dusters, etc. Virtually everything we see in the castle was once a person. The “people” hold clothes in their drawers, fill the china cabinet, and even the footstool by the fire used to be a dog.

Where is all the “real” stuff? Did they dump all the real dishes in the trash and take their place in the cupboards (which seems horrifying, by the way — spending your days as one in a stack of dishes!)  Is there a disused lavatory in the basement where they have hidden all the real wardrobes, footstools, etc.?

Comment: https://img.ifunny.co/images/f9e20afcfb0fdcce95ce89647d7fed68bbb5be3e8f5c576f7a4d3709c6afc7af_1.jpg

Comment: There are two separate questions here; A) *"Where's all the original furniture"* and B) *"Why did the guests and staff act like the furniture they'd turned into"*

Comment: I always wondered what they called Chip before he lost the chip of porcelain from his teacup head....and why, when restored to humanity, he didn't have a big chunk of his skull and head missing

Comment: I don’t really see how this question lacked focus as-is, but I’ve removed the “second question” and now I think it’s laser-focused!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - Great. Now re-ask the second question as a new question. That one's also answerable.

Comment: @DannyMcG He was missing a tooth, though.

Comment: @DannyMcG - His father calls him Chip at the end of the new film.

Comment: My personal theory is that inhabitants of the castle were not _transformed_ into "new" household items, but rather _merged_ with the existing household item they kinda resembled or were related to. Take the maid at the end of the movie: she was a duster while cursed, and after the curse is broken she transforms into a woman... who is herself holding a duster. I take that as meaning that the cursed duster was actually the fusion of the original duster and the woman who used it daily. After the curse is broken, everything is splitted back into the original person and the original item.

Comment: @walen I love that idea!

Comment: @DannyMcG [you're not the first person to ask that question](https://i.imgur.com/tEfKHwL.jpg)

Comment: @MikeTheLiar cheers for that link, that's exactly how I imagined it!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If we take the 2017 film tie-in [*Lost in a Book*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33412061-beauty-and-the-beast) at face value, the Beast seems to have smashed a considerable amount of non-sentient furniture, fixtures and crockery.

> *It had been dark in the Beast’s chambers, but Belle’s eyes had soon adjusted. As she’d moved through the once-beautiful rooms, she’d seen that all the fine furniture they contained had been broken; the costly bed hangings, shredded; the gilt mirrors, smashed.*

Presumably mobile plates and footstools are harder to get hold of to destroy, hence their continued survival.

Comment: I hope Beast never mistakenly smashed a sentient furniture...

Comment: @Roberto - He seems to struggle with anger management issues but we don't see him committing outright murder

Comment: Yeah, yeah, but I'd imagine when you're angry, it's hard to differentiate between a cup of tea and a talking cup of tea. Maybe that's how Chip got his chip? I'm just joking 

Comment: @Roberto - I'm assuming his name is ironic. His father calls him Chip (at the end of the new film) and he's got a chipped tooth.