# Why do the people act like the household items they turn into?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast

(Split from [this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/228353/1253))

In Disney’s “Beauty and the Beast,” all the castle staff and livestock were, at some time in the past, turned into china , furniture, clocks, feather dusters, etc. These formerly-human objects are filling the roles of the real objects they resemble. The “people” hold clothes in their drawers, fill the china cabinet, and light the corridors.

What could possibly have been their motivation for taking the place of the “real” inanimate objects — wouldn’t it be better to leave the dusting to the “real” feather dusters, after all? Wouldn’t being shaped like a dish be indignity enough, let alone allowing strangers to eat off your back?

Comment: The real feather dusters have no-one to operate them :-)

Comment: It might be the other way around. Subservient people became service objects, etc.

Comment: "These formerly-human objects are filling the roles of the real objects they resemble... What could possibly have been their motivation...?" Why [Mr Zimbardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_prison_experiment), I'm sure I have no idea.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Dark, but incisive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the servants (and guests) are trapped in hell. They can't escape from the castle, nor are they able to usefully fulfil their functions as servants.

> [Life is so unnerving](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwtwb4g1qsk)
>   For a servant who's not serving
>   He's not whole without a soul to wait upon
>   Ah, those good old days when we were useful
>   Suddenly those good old days are gone
>   Ten years we've been rusting
>   Needing so much more than dusting
>   Needing exercise, a chance to use our skills
>   Most days we just lay around the castle
>   Flabby, fat and lazy

Waiting on Belle or the Beast or indeed doing *anything* that breaks up the monotony of their existence is seen as vastly preferable to simply lying around and doing nothing, hence why the plates and cutlery (the dancing guests) have spent so much time practicing such an elaborate dance routine, one that, as an added bonus, allows them to taste the fine cuisine prepared by the chef.

> Try the grey stuff, it's delicious
>   Don't believe me? Ask the dishes

You may wish to note that all of the forms chosen still allow the servants to do *the thing that they were hired for*, in some cases far more efficiently than as humans.